Punctuation convention to identify propositional contents
I want to know if there is a conventional or acceptable use of punctuation to identify the contents of a proposition. Consider, for example:

Alice believes that both P and it is rational to believe that E requires belief in P.

Hideous. I want to be able to eliminate ambiguity and enable nesting without creating an unreadable sentence or continually offsetting and naming the propositions. Ideally, I think it would look something like this, replacing the '*' with whatever punctuation mark is acceptable:

Alice believes *P and it is rational to believe *E requires belief in P.**

I think quotation marks would introduce an ambiguity that I would prefer to ignore in the present context (think "Alice believes "Clark Kent can fly"" vs. "Alice believes "Superman can fly""). And I would hope this convention would apply outside of the context of attributing beliefs, as well. For example:

The proposition *P and it is rational to believe P* is beautiful.

Thanks!
